# Symfony EasyAdmin v4 - how to use COUNT in custom filters?

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

In symfony 6 and Easy Admin 4 i've got a entity Rates which contains an author column. I can't make a filter that counts all of authors and returns only this one that appears there more than a 3 times. I've tried:

```
  $queryBuilder->having('COUNT(entity.author) >= 3');
  $queryBuilder->groupBy('entity.author');
```

and when i dumped query result using `dump($queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult());`
i can see the proper result but EasyAdmin shows 'No results.'

Is it possible to do that?